# Manipulating Tables (or lists) in Mathematcia

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

For scientific purposes (code research) I am using Mathematica to enumerate all periodic sequences of some linear recurrences. As an example the command

```
Table[{Mod[i * 2^n + j * 4^n + k * 6^n, 7] },{i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 5}, {n, 0, 5}]
```

allows to enumerate all 216 distinct periodic sequences of linear recurrent sequences in a finite field of order 7 (or mod 7) with characteristic polynomial whose roots are 2,4 and 6. The first five sequences it produces are:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6}, {2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3}, …
```

I have two questions:

i) The first sequence is obtained when `i=0,j=0,k=0;` the second when `i=0,j=0,k=1,` the third when `i=0,j=0,k=2,` etc. Is there a way to join these numbers with the sequence they generate so that I will get to know these parameters and therefore to be able to, later (if needed), generate a particular sequence? That is I would like that the output would be something like this

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},  {{1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6}, {0, 0, 1}},  {{2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5}, {0, 0, 2}} , etc.
```

ii) In the example above (3rd order linear recurrence, and mod 7) the number of sequences obtained (216) is manageable by hand; but this number grows very quickly when the linear recurrence has order higher than 3 and the field has characteristic higher than 7. And, in those cases, most of the sequences that are produced are of no interest to me. I think that I could throw away at least 99% of the sequences that do not interest me if I could add an instruction that would read the output (the sequences obtained) and would say “I only want the sequences such that the products of its elements is 216 (say)”: from the five sequences above only `{1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6}` would remain because 1x6x1x6x1x6=216$; or “I only want the sequences such that the products of its elements is 216 or 1000 (say)” from the five sequences above `{1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6}` and `{2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5}` would remain because 1x6x1x6x1x6 = 216 and 2x5x2x5x2x 5=1000.

Is it possible to do this? I tried some list and tables manipulation, but had no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_. Please add what you've tried so far and on which part you are having an issue that makes you unable to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

here is the first part..

```
Flatten[Table[{Table[Mod[i*2^n + j*4^n + k*6^n, 7], {n, 0, 5}], {i, j,
     k}}, {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 5}], 2]
```

> {{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6}, {0, 0, 
>      1}}, {{2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5}, {0, 0, 2}}, {{3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 
>      3}},...

better way:

```
{Table[Mod[#.{2, 4, 6}^n, 7], {n, 0, 5}],#} & /@ Tuples[Range[0, 5], {3}]
```

example finding cases with a specified product:

```
Reap[Do[
        s = Table[Mod[i*2^n + j*4^n + k*6^n, 7], {n, 0, 5}]; 
        If[Times @@ s == 81, Sow[{s, {i, j, k}}]],
     {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 5}]][[2, 1]]
```

> {{{3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 0}}, {{3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 
>      0}}, {{1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 0}}}

Comment: I already knew the Reap/Sow command but I had completely forgot about it.

Thank you! This works fine! That's exactly what I need. Thanks.